# How to center an element horizontally and vertically regardless of other elements before and after it?

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/joshuajazleung/pen/JyONYa

```
<main>
  <header>Logo</header>
  <div class="center">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, laudantium, nam in quia aspernatur animi aut sit eum officia minima cumque obcaecati fugit numquam accusantium distinctio quas recusandae repudiandae reiciendis.</p>
  </div>
</main>

html, body, main {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
}

.center {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Here I want to center that `.center` div horizontally and vertically using flexbox absolutely on the `<main>` element. But with the existence of `<header>`, that `.center` shifts down slightly because `<header>` took some space on the `<main>`. How can I achieve absolute centering?

Comment: http://howtocenterincss.com/

Comment: Did it answered your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your header to absolute so it is ignored by all other elements.

```
header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
}
```

```css
html,
body,
main {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
}

.center {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>Logo</header>
  <div class="center">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, laudantium, nam in quia aspernatur animi aut sit eum officia minima cumque obcaecati fugit numquam accusantium distinctio quas recusandae repudiandae reiciendis.</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `position: absolute` to the header instead. This will take the header out of the normal flow, so that the `.center` element will become centered within the overall `<main>` element.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```css
html, body, main {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>Logo</header>
  <div class="center">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, laudantium, nam in quia aspernatur animi aut sit eum officia minima cumque obcaecati fugit numquam accusantium distinctio quas recusandae repudiandae reiciendis.</p>
  </div>
</main>
```